# Jquery Ajax Response

Tags: php, jquery

Este es mi código

```
controller =  $("#src_controller").val();
source_id =  '#' + $("#src_filter_tags").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data:"id=" + $(this).data('tagId'),
    dataType: "json",
    url: "index.php?controller=" + controller + "&action=FindByTag",
    success: function(response){
        var resultArray = [];
        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
            resultArray.push(v.*);
        });
        console.log('#' + $("#src_filter_tags").val());
        $(source_id).val(resultArray);
        return 1;
    },error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

lo que quiero es en la linea
    resultArray.push(v.*);
el asterisco es el nombre del campo que me traigo de la base de datos.

Quiero que cambie de forma dinámica, es decir, asignarle una variable a ese asterisco para que con cada iteración del each me coja una variable distinta.

Otra solucion sería obtener el primer valor de lo que me traigo por JSON.

El problema es que según a que tabla de mi base de datos pregunte los campos ids son diferentes.

Por ejemplo

Tabla1 => id_tabla1
Tabla2 => id_tabla2

Por lo que lo que quiero hacer es 
variable = id_tabla1 o id_tabla2
resultArray.push(v.variable);

Lo he conseguido hacer así:

```
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
    $.each(v, function( k, v ) {
        resultArray.push(v);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Quiero hacer esto de forma más limpia

Comment: Hola Subiendo, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta para que pueda ser reabierta y completa el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento general del sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Answer (score 1):

Habría que ver cómo es el código servidor que genera la respuesta, pero lo que yo haría sería "normalizar" los nombres de campos para que el código cliente no tenga que decidir nada.

Es decir, sin importar de qué tabla de la base de datos se trate, enviar las respuestas siempre con los mismos nombres de campo.